# how to repair xampp server

Tags: mysql, xampp

1. Go to MySQL config file (my file at `C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini`)
2. Check for the line `innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend`
3. Next check the `ibdata1` file exist under `C:/xampp/mysql/data/`
4. If file does not exist copy the `ibdata1` file from location `C:\xampp\mysql\backup\ibdata1`

This solution may loss my database or tables? please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

ibdata1 contains InnoDB dictionary which is vitally important for InnoDB. If you delete it any access to a table will fail with Table doesn't exist error.